# Is this the right way to format foot notes?

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

Using the command

```
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
\noindent\makebox[.02\columnwidth][l]{\@thefnmark}%
\parbox[t]{.98\columnwidth}{#1}}
```

I got the desired result for the foot notes, as shown in the image below.

I'd like to know if my code is the best way to do this.

[image]

**edited:** using `footmisc` with the option `hang` as suggested, the format of the foot number is different so the vertical space around the foot note is changed.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea.  Add `\setcounter{footnote}{8}` (or `{98}`!) to see why not.  Also, what is wrong, e.g., with the `hang` option of `footmisc.sty`?

Comment: I like `KOMA-Script`'s `\deffootnote` (available to standard classes via the `scrextend` package) for these kind of things.

Comment: @jon, I can imagine what you're trying to exemplify. I'll try soon. But now I believe that the left alignment could solve the problem and the length of the box would be enough to the number. I'll check your suggestion. About the package, I don't know if some powerful package could change something on my format rules. I have a lot of modifications and I'm afraid that some package could affect it so deeply that I'd notice later.

Comment: @Sigur -- It is a possible danger, I guess, but `footmisc` was designed (carefully, I'd guess) by someone who knows and understands (La)TeX very well.  If you're worried about bad interactions, it will more likely be due to your 'lot of modifications' (what are you doing that is so crazy?), not bad interactions between `footmisc` and other standard packages.  And, if there is, it would be good to find out so a fix can be made for future users!  One of the strengths of LaTeX is that there is a large user base, which serves LaTeX well for finding package bugs and conflicts.

Answer (score 8):

With `scrextend`, a package that is part of the [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle, one can use KOMA's command

```
\deffootnote[<mark width>]{<indent>}{<parindent>}{<definition>}
```

with the standard classes for formatting footnotes. The following figure (taken from the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/scrguien)) illustrates the different values:

[image]

Inside the `<definition>` one can refer to the footnote mark with `\thefootnotemark`. Footnotes defined this way also work with [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1.5em]{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\space}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter

% we want to see what happens for two digit footnote numbers
\setcounter{footnote}{8} 

a\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}b\footnote{\lipsum[2]\lipsum*[3]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can customize the appearance of the footnotes with the `footmisc` package. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}

% do this \AtBeginDocument so that all font settings will be already made
\AtBeginDocument{
 % set the \footnotemargin to 1.5em at \footnotesize
 \footnotesize\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1.5em}\normalsize
 % set the footnote parindent equal to the normal parindent
 \edef\hangfootparindent{\the\parindent}
 % no parskip in foonotes
 \renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text
\begin{document}
\mainmatter

% we want to see what happens for two digit footnote numbers
\setcounter{footnote}{8} 

a\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}b\footnote{\lipsum[2]\lipsum*[3]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can set differently the parameters; just remember that `\hangfootparindent` and `\hangfootparskip` are macros, rather than lengths.

The `\edef` trick is used to store the current value of `\parindent`.

***Note*** The hyperlinks of `hyperref` don't work with `footmisc`, so one has to say

```
\hypersetup{hyperfootnotes=false}
```

if `hyperref` is loaded.

With your attempt, you lose the possibility of breaking a footnote across pages, which is undesirable in general, but sometimes is the only option, particularly for long footnotes.

---

A way to get footnote marks in the footnote not to be superscripted is the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sigur@makefnmark}{\@thefnmark}
\pretocmd{\@makefntext}{\let\@makefnmark\sigur@makefnmark}{}{}
\makeatother
```

We patch the `\@makefntext` so that a different macro is used for typesetting the footnote number. This won't work if you have footnotes to footnotes, of course. It's safe to change the meaning of `\@makefnmark` because `\@makefntext` is expanded in a group, so this change will not affect the typesetting of footnote marks in the text.

Comment: Great. How to use the foot note number on the foot note text not in `textsuperscript`?

Comment: Using your suggestion, as you can see here *http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/2280/shutterseleo005.png* the vertical alignment is not the same. I used the border of the window as horizontal rule.

Comment: @Sigur I can't see anything; what vertical alignment are you referring to?

Comment: The position of the foot note rule is not the same. I believe that some margin had changed.

Comment: @Sigur The position of the footnote rule depends on the size of the footnotes, it's not in a fixed position on the page. If I write two pages with the same footnotes at the end, I get perfect alignment.

Comment: but in both examples the foot note text has the same 6 lines from `\lipsum` command. Strange.

Comment: @Sigur Are you using flush bottom or ragged bottom?

Comment: For what? I'm using `foo \vfill \noindent non indented numbered line \hfill end of the\footnote{\lipsum[3]} line` to push down the text to see the size of the total text height.

Comment: @Sigur What class are you using? If it's `report` (oneside) or `article`, the bottom of the pages are not necessarily aligned to each other. With `book` (twoside) they are.

Comment: I'm using personalized `report` class but that two images are not from 2 pages of the document; they are from the same code (1 page only) but using/not using your solution. Let me study your suggestion. Thanks.